# PHP Script Running Via Cronjob on One Server but not on Similar Server

Tags: php, mysql

I was running this script via a cronjob on one server (VPS WHM) and copied everything over to another host with the same type of VPS and WHM.  This script is not running on the new server and or the emails are not being sent.  I have tried to troubleshoot it with the provider and they are at a loss.  My question is what setting could possibly cause such an issue?  I have messed with seemingly every setting on the server with little to no results.  Any information that would be helpful in tracking this down, let me know and I will edit the question.  If you have a guess that would be helpful as well, I am just looking for fresh eyes on this problem.

More Info:

Apache Version  2.2.27
PHP Version 5.4.31
MySQL Version   5.5.40-cll

No Errors in the logs

The Cron is : 10    4   *   *   * php /home/xxxxx/public_html/alert.php

I have also tried: 10   4   *   *   * /home/xxxxx/public_html/alert.php

```
    #!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_username = "xxxx"; 
$db_pass = "xxxx"; 
$db_name = "xxxxxx"; 
mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");

$headers = "Bcc: xxxxx@xxxx.com";

$tierasql =  "SELECT date,phonenumber,email, SUM(dataplan) AS currentplantiera, SUM(datamb) AS value_sumtiera FROM maindata2 WHERE dataplan BETWEEN 2 and 50 and dataplan != '20' GROUP BY email";


$resulttiera = mysql_query($tierasql);
while ($rowtiera = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulttiera)){
if ($resulttiera){
  $rowtiera = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulttiera);
  $plantiera = $rowtiera['currentplantiera'] ;
  $date = $rowtiera['date'] ;
  $inventorytiera = ROUND ($rowtiera["value_sumtiera"],2) ;
  $recipienttiera = $rowtiera['email'];
  if ($inventorytiera > (.75 * $plantiera)){
    $msgtiera = "Xxxxxxxxx Data Usage Alert:

This alert is being provided to you because your lines in Tier A have exceeded 75% of your Xxxxxxxxx Service Plan. 

As of $date, your current data usage is $inventorytiera MB and you have a data allotment of $plantiera MB of shared data. 

Please note that you may experience overage charges if your total data usage exceeds the net total usage of all data in the same sharing tier until your usage is reset on your next billing cycle.  

One upward rate plan adjustment is allowed per billing cycle, please visit http://xxxxxxxxx.com/rate-plan-change for more details.

Please refer to Xxxxxxxxx.com/data to review your data usage.";
    mail($recipienttiera,"xxxxx@xxxx.com", "Xxxxxxxxx Data Usage Alert", $msgtiera, $headers);
  }
}
else {
  $msg = "An error occurred: " . mysql_error();
  mail($recipienttiera,"xxxxx@xxxx.com", "Alert from Xxxxxxxxx error", $msgtiera, $headers);

}
}

$tierbsql =  "SELECT date,phonenumber,email, SUM(dataplan) AS currentplantierb, SUM(datamb) AS value_sumtierb FROM maindata2 WHERE dataplan BETWEEN 500 and 8000 GROUP BY email";


$resulttierb = mysql_query($tierbsql);
while ($rowtierb = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulttierb)){
if ($resulttierb){
  $rowtierb = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulttierb);
  $plantierb = $rowtierb['currentplantierb'] ;
  $date = $rowtierb['date'] ;
  $inventorytierb = ROUND ($rowtierb["value_sumtierb"],2) ;
  $recipienttierb = $rowtierb['email'];
  if ($inventorytierb > (.75 * $plantierb)){
    $msgtierb = "Xxxxxxxxx Data Usage Alert:

This alert is being provided to you because your lines in Tier B have exceeded 75% of your Xxxxxxxxx Service Plan. 

As of $date, your current data usage is $inventorytierb MB and you have a data allotment of $plantierb MB of shared data.  

Please note that you may experience overage charges if your total data usage exceeds the net total usage of all data in the same sharing tier until your usage is reset on your next billing cycle.  

One upward rate plan adjustment is allowed per billing cycle, please visit http://xxxxxxxxx.com/rate-plan-change for more details.

Please refer to Xxxxxxxxx.com/data to review your data usage.";
    mail($recipienttierb,"xxxxx@xxxx.com", "Xxxxxxxxx Data Usage Alert", $msgtierb, $headers);
  }
}
else {
  $msg = "An error occurred: " . mysql_error();
  mail($recipienttierb,"xxxxx@xxxx.com", "Alert from Xxxxxxxxx error", $msg, $headers);

}
}

$tiercsql =  "SELECT date,phonenumber,email, SUM(dataplan) AS currentplantierc, SUM(datamb) AS value_sumtierc FROM maindata2 WHERE dataplan BETWEEN 10000 and 100000 GROUP BY email";


$resulttierc = mysql_query($tiercsql);
while ($rowtierc = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulttierc)){
if ($resulttierc){
  $rowtierc = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulttierc);
  $plantierc = $rowtierc['currentplantierc'] ;
  $date = $rowtierc['date'] ;
  $inventorytierc = ROUND ($rowtierc["value_sumtierc"],2) ;
  $recipienttierc = $rowtierc['email'];
  if ($inventorytierc > (.75 * $plantierc)){
    $msgtierc = "Xxxxxxxxx Data Usage Alert:

This alert is being provided to you because your lines in Tier B have exceeded 75% of your Xxxxxxxxx Service Plan. 

As of $date, your current data usage is $inventorytierc MB and you have a data allotment of $plantierc MB of shared data.  

Please note that you may experience overage charges if your total data usage exceeds the net total usage of all data in the same sharing tier until your usage is reset on your next billing cycle.  

One upward rate plan adjustment is allowed per billing cycle, please visit http://xxxxxxxxx.com/rate-plan-change for more details.

Please refer to Xxxxxxxxx.com/data to review your data usage.";
    mail($recipienttierc,"xxxxx@xxxx.com", "Xxxxxxxxx Data Usage Alert", $msgtierc, $headers);
  }
}
else {
  $msg = "An error occurred: " . mysql_error();
  mail($recipienttierc,"xxxxx@xxxx.com", "Alert from Xxxxxxxxx error", $msg, $headers);

}
}


$sql =  "SELECT date,phonenumber,email, dataplan AS currentplan, SUM(datamb) AS value_sum FROM maindata2 GROUP BY phonenumber, dataplan";


$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $plan = $row['currentplan'] ;
            $date = $row['date'] ;
            $inventory = ROUND ($row["value_sum"],2) ;
            $recipient = $row['email'];
            $line = $row['phonenumber'];
            if ($inventory > (.75 * $plan)) {
    $msg = "Xxxxxxxxx Single Line Usage Alert:

This alert is being provided to you because your line $line has exceeded 75% of it's Xxxxxxxxx Service Plan.   

As of $date, your current data usage is $inventory MB of your $plan MB data plan. 

Please note that you may experience overage charges if your total data usage exceeds the net total usage of all data in the same sharing tier until your usage is reset on your next billing cycle.  

One upward rate plan adjustment is allowed per billing cycle, please visit http://xxxxxxxxx.com/rate-plan-change for more details.

Please refer to Xxxxxxxxx.com/data to review your data usage.";
    mail($recipient,"xxxxx@xxxx.com", "Alert from Xxxxxxxxx", $msg, $headers);
  }
}
}
else {
  $msg = "An error occurred: " . mysql_error();
  mail($recipient,"xxxxx@xxxx.com", "Alert from Xxxxxxxxx error", $msg, $headers);

}




        ?>
```

Comment: which version of php is installed?

Comment: Apache Version 2.2.27
PHP Version 5.4.31
MySQL Version 5.5.40-cll

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your php-cli error logs on the new server? It's probably erroring out when running. If there are no errors in the logs then it could possibly not be running at all. Try triggering the job manually using the php command to see if it succeeds, then add it to the cron and check error logs.